# unicode-math.sty ver 0.8c

Tags: xetex, miktex, unicode-math

I need unicode-math.sty of ver 0.8c exactly (from unicode-math.tar.lzma of MikTex) for some experiments. Now I can find only 0.8d. I tried convert from unicode-math.dtx, but it seems to be too different. Unfortunately, package hasn't version number in its name. Could it possible to find it anywhere? Maybe is there some tex-archive with various versions?

Comment: Here you go: [link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=21169218653102553492)

Comment: O! Thank you! It seems that it is just I need!

Comment: How to set the question as answered?

Comment: Ok I'll convert my comment to an answer tomorrow. EDIT: Or I won't, because Torbjørn's answer is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've uploaded `unicode-math.sty` version 0.8c for you [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=21169218653102553492).

Answer (score 2):

Will Robertson who maintains `unicode-math` keeps the code on GitHub, so you can get the various releases from

- https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/releases

Comment: Thank you, but I know it and I tried to convert unicode-math.dtx of 0.8c to unicode-math.sty, but how I pointed (in the question) -- it seems to be too different (perhaps, because of missed options or due to my poor qualification), i.e. there are not a unicode-math.sty in sources in this code on GitHub.

Comment: @Vladimir In that case I've added my answer after all.

Comment: @Vladimir Ah, right, sorry.